# How can I catch the log output of pyspark foreachPartition?

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming

pyspark

when I use print() in foreachRdd method, it work!

```
def echo(data):
print data
....
lines = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, brokerUrl, topics)

topic_rdd = lines.map(lambda x: get_topic_rdd(x)).filter(lambda x: x[0]!= None)

topic_rdd.foreachRDD(lambda x: echo(x))
```

I can look at the log in console with the spark-on-yarn

But if I use the method of foreachPartition ,it can't see any log of print()

```
topic_rdd = lines.map(lambda x: get_topic_rdd(x)).filter(lambda x: x[0]!= None)

topic_rdd.foreachRDD(lambda x: x.foreachPartition(lambda y: echo(y)))
```

IF I want to see the log, I need to enter the different partitions to look the log ? Can I see the log in the Single console.By the way ,I can see the log in the Single console with scala but python.

Answer (score 1):

rdd.foreachRDD is runing on **driver** node which sending message to your Terminnal

rdd.foreachPartition is runing on **worker** node which sending message to **worker**'s Terminnal you can not see that

If you want see logs just save them as files